# Tabs PCF in Guidewire Studio (IntelliJ) won't close - Question and answer

Tags: intellij-idea, tabs, guidewire

I have a problem with Guidewire Studio (based on IntelliJ) where the .pcf files tabs  wouldn't close. I would click on the x or on the mouse wheel, they would close and open right back. Tried turning off and on GW, rebooting my machine, nothing works.

Comment: This is good information to know, but I think it needs to be edited into a question, and then an answer, it is acceptable to answer your own question, so I'd suggest you do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How to do it:

You have to close the project (File/Close project) and open it back, the tabs are still open but you can finally close them!

Answer (score 0):

Please try this way, In bottom of left corner of that .pcf tab, it has 2 tabs:- 
1. Config.... 2. Text, 
so open text and close that tab by x.